# Probability in Combination of 5 colour in 9 spaces

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 5 colours: red, green, blue, black and white, and 9 spaces to paint with only one of that colours each. What is the probability of having 5 spaces in white and the other 4 all in different colours?

Please explain all the steps you take to get to the result. Thank you.

Probability=(all the case that have 5 W and one of each other colour)/(all the combinations possible)

Comment: Probability? Well, that depends. You could decide to do the painting exactly as you describe and then the probability that it occurs is quite close to $1$. So more information is needed. Btw, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @drhab, did you mean close to 1 or 0?

Comment: What I essentially mean is that you cannot say sensible things about probability if there is no information with what probability things happen. What e.g. is the probability that a space is painted in green? You don't make any mention of that. I think you are after numbers of possibilities here.  You could add that each possibility has the same probability. Then finally it is a question concerning probability.

Comment: We assume that all colour sequences are equally likely. (This should be in some form part of the statement of the problem.) There are $5^9$ such sequences. Now count how many sequences there are with $5$ W and one each of the others.

Comment: i mean, the probability is: 
(number of possible cases that are 5 W and one of each other)/(all the possible cases)

Comment: The solution is 0.0015 but I dont know how to get there.

Comment: There are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to choose where the white goes. For each, there are $4!$ ways to arrange the other colours.

Comment: Permutations of 5 different groups, one of cardinality 5 and the others of cardinality 1, so the answer is $\frac{9!}{5!1!1!1!1!}$. You must divide this by the total of possibilities that is $5^9$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I agree with your solution thank you.
It is definitely the right answer.